# React-Router : Unable to redirect from / to /home

Tags: reactjs, react-router, router

I am using react-router for routing in my application. Here is the router config.

```
let routes = {
    path : "/",
    onEnter : ({},replace) => replace('/home'),
    childRoutes : [
        {
            path : "home",
            component : App,
            indexRoute : {component : Landing},
            childRoutes : [ ]
        }
    ]
}
```

When I try to load application I get `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`. As per my understanding, this is because of onEnter in "/" which run every time I try to hit anything. Is there a way that it only executes when I hit exact match "/" and not every time ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `indexRoute` to redirect to home route (see [index redirects](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/IndexRoutes.md#index-redirects) last example):

```
let routes = {
    path : "/",
    indexRoute: { onEnter: (nextState, replace) => replace('/home') },
    childRoutes : [
        {
            path : "home",
            component : App,
            indexRoute : {component : Landing},
            childRoutes : [ ]
        }
    ]
}
```